# Braintree Gateway - Google Cloud Platform

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-compute-engine, braintree, braintree-sandbox

How do I configure my Braintree Production account to Go Live on my website that I created on Google Cloud Platform? I currently have a Braintree Sandbox account configured through Woocommerce and it seems to work fine, however, I'm not sure how or where to configure server-side code to connect API calls to the Braintree gateway.

Comment: Can you edit your question to be more specific? Where are you unsure how to change to your production account: in Braintree, WooCommerce, or Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: Hello, I was trying to change this in WooCommerce, I apologize for not being specific. I actually figured out how to do this by first disconnecting from my Braintree account, and then reconnecting and manually entering credentials. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things and here's what worked.

I'm using a WooCommerce plugin that connects to Braintree. I first disconnected from my Braintree Sandbox account in WooCommerce. I then reconnected to Braintree and selected the option to manually enter credentials, which I completed using my live credentials.

Thanks!